# Identify this movie/telefilm featuring Heather Graham

Tags: identify-this-movie

I once watched a movie or telefim. Here are the details I remember:

- The main actress was Heather Graham. The story revolves around her.
- She wanted to be a music superstar, but working as a waitress in a restaurant. The money was the main hurdle in achieving her dream (this is what she thought).
- In restaurant, she used to meet several customers who wanted to lure her into prostitute business or something like that.
- She got a boyfriend at beach. She was sleeping and then a guy came to ask if she had extra cigarettes and then he pulled out cigarettes. This is how they met for the first time.
- Initially, the boyfriend used to encourage her for her dreams. Later, he made her take drugs and then she became a drug addict.
- One day, she broke up with him because of the drug issues. She wanted her old dreamy life back.
- Later, this ex-boyfriend came to the restaurant and ask her to leave with him. Upon refusal, he pulled out gun and made everyone there hostage. The plan was: Loot out all of the money there (restaurant's and customers') and run away with the girl.
- Then, police came outside and started threatening him. Due to fear, he accidentally murdered someone.
- The actress unwillingly agreed to run away with him, but in the process of escape (Window glass breaking or something like that), she had a chance to grab the gun.
- After some thought, she pulled the trigger to kill him.

Can you please identify this movie/telefilm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Broken](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469045/combined) from 2006.

> The aspirant singer Hope leaves Cleveland to Los Angeles expecting to succeed in the career of rock-and-roll singer. She meets the funny Will on the beach and they fall in love for each other. However, Will [gets her addicted to] heroin, destroying her dreams. Later, Hope escapes from Will, trying to put her life back on the trails and working as waitress in the Blue Star Café. However, one night she is caught by Will that wants her back with him.

Here's the trailer:

Comment: Sorry about that, would've been faster but my browser stalled. :P